# CSS only - Make an animation happen in 3 steps

Tags: css

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-moon-853e2k?file=/src/App.js:0-278

I want the pink circle to move in steps but it keeps moving in continuous fashion:
[image]
I tried using `steps(3)` `steps(3,end)` but none of that is working:

```css
.Spinner {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.DotLoader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.DotLoader section {
  height: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e5e4e5;
}

.DotLoader div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: pink;
  left: 3rem;
  animation: moveSpinner 1s steps(3, end) infinite;
}

@keyframes moveSpinner {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: 1.5rem;
  }
  100% {
    left: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Spinner">
  <div class="DotLoader">
    <div></div>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me understand this and fix it?

Comment: The pink circle is not moving continuously, try slowing the animation down to say 10seconds per iteration and you will see it 'jerks' along. However, can you define more closely what effect you actually want? Are each of the static gray dots to 'light up' (turn pink) in turn or is the pink element really separate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.DotLoader div {
   animation: moveSpinner 1s steps(3) infinite;
}

@keyframes moveSpinner {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 112%;
  }
}
```

Comment: May I know how have you come up with the calculation of 112%?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand... If you want to make the pink circle "move and stop" on each gray circles, you can simply delete `steps(3, end)`. There is no need for it it just smoothly slides from one dot to another.

But if the request is making pink one just jump instead of slide, then you do not need another `<div>` for that, just create animations for your `<section>` elements individually. Light them up as pink and make them gray again.

Comment: Hmm Can you give the example on sandbox or something?